# RadGrid1.Items is null

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

```
enter code here protected void btnshortlist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in rg_results.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkselected = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkselected");
        if (chkselected.Checked == true)
        {
            Applicant_Status(item.Cells[3].Text.Trim(), 1, 0);
        }
    }
 }
```

**rg_results.Items** is null and cannot enter in foreach loops 
Note:I'm not using Rad Grid Need Data Source Event because it is conflict with my javascripts
please help me?

Answer (score 1):

use **rg_results.MasterTableView.Items** instead of **rg_results.Items**